# Convergent $x_n,y_n$ and $x_n^{y_n}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x_n, y_n > 0$.

I need an example of convergent sequences $x_n,y_n$ such that $x_n^{y_n}$ diverges. Could you help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $x_n$ be any positive sequence converging to $0$. Let $y_n$ be $1/|\ln x_n|$ if $n$ is even and let $y_n$ be $2/|\ln x_n|$ if $n$ is odd. Note that $y_n$ converges to $0$. Then $x_n^{y_n}=e^{y_n\cdot \ln x_n}$ which is $e^{-1}$ or $e^{-2}$, alternating with $n$, thus not converging.

Comment: Brilliant! How did you come up with it?

Answer (score 0):

$$x_n=\frac{1}{n!}\\y_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\\x_n^{y_n}=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 \frac{1}{n!}^{\frac{-1}{n}}&  \space\space n=2k+1\\ 
 \frac{1}{n!}^{\frac{+1}{n}}& \space\space  n=2k
\end{matrix}\right.$$ 
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
 \sqrt[n]{n!} \rightarrow \frac{1}{e} & \space\space  n=2k+1\\ 
 \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n!}} \rightarrow  e & \space\space n=2k
\end{matrix}\right. $$

Comment: To dispel any illusion that the sought counterexample is hard it should be noted that one can construct trivial counterexamples easily. While this example is pretty, it somewhat misses the point of the exercise.

Comment: You missed the fact that you are supposed to have $y_n>0$......

Comment: oh ,yes .I miss $y_n>0$

Answer (score -1):

You can show easily that $x_n^{y_n}$ converges to $l_x^{l_y}$, with $l_x$ the limit of $x_n$ and $l_y$ the limit of $y_n$...

Just by using the right $\epsilon_{x,y}$ and $N_{x,y}$ in the definition of convergence.

Comment: Why? Are you saying that $x_n^{y_n}$ cannot diverge?

Comment: @nikolai Yes, it can't diverge.

Comment: strange, then it must be a mistake in my book.

Comment: the problem is that the quantity $0^0$ is not well-defined. The book is fine.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Right you are. I assumed limits were $>0$, but only $x_n,y_n>0$... My bad.